Gazebo demo not working
Anyone run sdf_parser.launch.py from the gazebo demos?
I have Gazebo Harmonic on Ubuntu 24.04 built from source. I tried to run the above demo and it throws an error in this line <uri>package://ros_gz_sim_demos/models/vehicle</uri>that it cannot find the model.
I tried modifying it to this <uri>model://vehicle</uri> but still get the same error.
Tried also from the binary installation and still getting the same error.
What could be wrong?
Edit: Reply to the answer of @JustPtrck
I wanted to see how the tf tree is structured. My tf tree is similat to the tf tree from another example namely tf_bridge.launch.py
TF tree of the example:

My TF tree:

In my TF tree I don't understand why all the sensors are not under the x500_lidar_2d/base_link frame.
In my sdf file all my sensors have this tag:
<pose relative_to="base_link">0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>

And a separate joint definition such as:
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>imu_link</child>
  </joint>


Seems like this file has not been updated in the jazzy branch of ros_gz.
vehicle.sdf is outdated, it uses the old ignition::gazebo namespaces instead of the new gz::sim. Which should definitely cause issues.

     <plugin
       filename="ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system"
       name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">
       <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
       <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
       <wheel_separation>1.25</wheel_separation>
       <wheel_radius>0.3</wheel_radius>
       <odom_publish_frequency>1</odom_publish_frequency>
       <max_linear_acceleration>1</max_linear_acceleration>
       <min_linear_acceleration>-1</min_linear_acceleration>
       <max_angular_acceleration>2</max_angular_acceleration>
       <min_angular_acceleration>-2</min_angular_acceleration>
       <max_linear_velocity>0.5</max_linear_velocity>
       <min_linear_velocity>-0.5</min_linear_velocity>
       <max_angular_velocity>1</max_angular_velocity>
       <min_angular_velocity>-1</min_angular_velocity>
     </plugin>


What is the reason you need this demo?
Maybe we can help you with your specific issue.
